# Maven2 problem to access plugins repository !

Tags: apache, maven-2

i just come to install maven2, after configuring the settings.xml in `${user.home}/.m2` and fixing a proxy error. Now by executing the command :

```
  mvn -U archetype:create -DgroupId=maven-test -DartifactId=maven-test     
    -DpackageName=net.ensode.maventest
```

i get this error :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'archetype'.
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from central
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'org.apache.maven.plugins' could not be retri
eved from repository: central due to an error: Authorization failed: Access deni
ed to: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml

[INFO] Repository 'central' will be blacklisted
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin' does not exi
st or no valid version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 29 16:05:40 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

any idea of what could cause it ?

thanks !

Comment: since you mention a proxy: does the proxy require auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the most likely cause is that your proxy requires you to authenticate, and you haven't configured the authentication details into your `settings.xml` file.

Comment: @stephenC & @bert : yes and i configured the proxy in settings.xml

Comment: Well I cannot think of any other explanation.  Maven Central does not require you to login to download plugins.

Comment: thanks to insist on proxy ! i changed the proxy adress and now it works.